# Finding the largest subscript of an array in a unssorted and repetitive array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I have an unsorted & repetitive array like {1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,4,4,4} , I would  like to find the largest number in the array and its largest position .For example 5 is repaetd twice and i would like to have the position of second 5.  How should i procced .I tried sorting the array in  reverse manner and  checking for next number and finding its location.Can this be done faster. Any clues ?

Comment: define `subscript`. Show us what you have done.

Comment: By the way reverse sorting is a waste of time as it is already sorted in the ascending order. Just iterate from the end.

Comment: it's not sorted (not even in your example). if it was sorted then the answer would simply be the last index of the array.

Comment: i have edited the Question now . its an unsorted array

Comment: sorting your array will mess up your problem set. shorner102 below has the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code returns the maximum number at the maximum position assuming that arr is your array of numbers.

```
int maxPosition = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[maxPosition] <= arr[i])
                maxPosition = i;
        }
        return maxPosition;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use java 8 this should work:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5);
int lastIndexOf = numbers.lastIndexOf(numbers.stream().max((x1, x2) -> x1 - x2).get());
```